# Tooltip load error

Tags: unity, 17.04

I have this strange issue when it comes to first loading a tooltip in Ubuntu 17.04.  When I do hover, it displays as the following... [funky tooltip rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A95s.png)

Any suggestions of what to do or how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google Chrome? It seems it's an [old bug of Google Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=442111).

I don't think there is an official way to fix this bug at this moment.

But there are some patches made by users.

See: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90264

Comment: Yes, I am using chrome.  I don't remember having this issue prior to 17.04, but it does seem to be isolated to chrome.  Thanks for the link!